# Use German Google Pay in the USA

Tags: usa, germany

For some weeks Google Pay has been available in Germany with a few banks. I'm traveling to the USA next week. Will I be able to use the "German" Google Pay with my linked credit card in the USA, where Google Pay is accepted?

If so, in what country is the deposit made from my credit card? I have to pay some additional fees if I pay with it outside of Europe.

Answer (score 2):

As long as Google Pay is accepted, you will be able to pay. All the transactions will be in the country's currency.

If, somehow, you're able to use your local currency to pay you should still use the credit cards currency converter as it is normaly cheaper than the currency converter of the service provider.